# Fetching links from multiple <ul> with same class

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get all links from the UL with the class list-chapter but I only get half the link I want because the links are separated in two `<ul>` that are inside a div like so `<div><ul>links1</ul><ul>links2</ul></div>`. I'm new to python and I am really stuck.

Also if possible I would like to add "http://www.example.com" before everylink and save them one by one in a list so I can access them with list[1].

Thanks, here is the code

```
# import libraries
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
"""Getting Started Example for Python 2.7+/3.3+"""

chapter = 1
chapterlist = 1
links = []
name = ""
reallink = ""
while chapter < 31:
    quote_page = Request('http://website.com/page.html?page=' + str(chapter) + '&per-page=50', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mosezilla/5.0'})
    page = urlopen(quote_page).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    name_box = soup.find("ul", attrs={"class": "list-chapter"})
    links += name_box.find_all("a")
    reallink += str([a['href'] for a in links])
    chapter += 1
f = open("links.txt", "w+")
i = 1
f.write(reallink)
f.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'separated in two'? Can you show an example?

Comment: My bad, inside the div.row are two ul.list-chapter

Comment: Could you copy and paste the exact HTML code of the `div` that you want to parse?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `find` which will return first match as opposed to `find_all` which would return a list of matches.

Assuming your `ul` class is correct I would use `select` instead and collect child `a` tags of those:

Replace these lines:

```
name_box = soup.find("ul", attrs={"class": "list-chapter"})
links += name_box.find_all("a")
reallink += str([a['href'] for a in links])
```

With

```
realinks = ['http://www.example.com' + item['href'] for item in soup.select('ul.list-chapter a')] #I'm assuming href already has leading /
```